# Creación de sockets TCP usando select

Tags: python, python-3.x, select, socket

Estoy haciendo una aplicación que funcione como un chat multiusuario empleando python3, de forma que los mensajs que escriba uno de los clientes en un terminal, se muestren por pantalla en el resto de terminales que están conectados en esa sesión de chat

La cosa es que no encuentro el fallo en mi código y al conectar el cliente a través del puerto de escucha del servidor, no consigo que los mensajes se muestre por pantalla.

Este sería el servidor.py

```
   # -*- coding: utf:8 -*-

import socket
import sys
import select

#Creando el socket TCP/IP
mi_Socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

mi_Socket.setblocking(0)

#Enlace de socket y puerto
hostname = socket.gethostname()
dns = socket.gethostbyname(hostname)

puerto = sys.argv[1]
dir_Servidor = (dns, (int(puerto)))

print("\nLevantamos %s puerto %s" %dir_Servidor)

mi_Socket.bind( dir_Servidor )

#Escuchando conexiones entrantes
mi_Socket.listen(5)

while 1:
    ready_to_read, ready_to_write, in_error = select.select([mi_Socket], [mi_Socket], [], 5)
    if len(ready_to_read) != 0:
        for i in ready_to_read:
            if i is mi_Socket:
                conexion_Cliente, dir_Cliente = i.accept()
                [i].append(conexion_Cliente)
                print ("Conectado a cliente: %s y puerto: %s " %dir_Cliente)
            else:
                print("Datos recibidos\n")
                datos = mi_Socket.recv(1024)

                if not datos:
                    [i].remove(i)
                else:
                    print("\nLos datos son: %s" &datos)

    if len(ready_to_write) != 0:
        for k in ready_to_write:
            k.send("Python select server from Ubuntu.\n")
```

Este sería el cliente.py:

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import socket
import select
import sys

#Creando un socket TCP/IP

mi_Socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

#Conecta el socket en el puerto cuando el servidor esté escuchando
hostname = socket.gethostname()
dns = socket.gethostbyname(hostname)

puerto = sys.argv[2]
dir_Servidor = (dns, puerto)

print ("\nconectando a %s puerto %s" %dir_Servidor)

mi_Socket.connect((dns, (int(puerto))))


while 1:
    ready_to_read, ready_to_write, in_error = select.select([mi_Socket], [mi_Socket], [], 5)
    if len(ready_to_read) != 0:
        buf = mi_Socket.recv(1024)
        if len(buf) != 0:
            print ("Datos recibidos: %s" &buf)
    if len(ready_to_write) != 0:
        mensaje = str.encode("Python select client from Ubuntu.\n")
        mi_Socket.send(mensaje)
```

Por linea de comandos, en el servidor escribo python3 python.py localhost 5050 (el puerto me daría igual) y en el cliente.py escribo python3 cliente.py 5050 (mismo que el servidor)

Comment: Si le dais en editar, podéis ver el código mejor. No sé como ponerlo para verlo más visual

Comment: Hola Adrian, bienvenido. Aunque he "arreglado" tu código para que salga en cajas de código con coloreado sintáctico, me he dado cuenta de que de todas formas está mal toda la indentación, además de cosas raras como `[i].remove(i)`. Probablemente resultado de un mal copia&pega. Lee el siguiente enlace para ver cómo hacer el pegado de código correctamente y arregla por favor lo que has puesto: https://bit.ly/SOesPASTE

Comment: Listo, modificado el código. Ahora sí que se ve presentable. Gracias a @abulafia

Comment: A ver si alguien me puede ayudar a ver el fallo, llevo ya tiempo y no consigo verlo

Answer (score 1):

Hay varios fallos en tu código:

- El más importante: en el servidor la lista que le pasas a `select()` tiene siempre un solo elemento: `[mi_Socket]`, que es el socket pasivo (o de escucha). Por tanto podrás recibir clientes nuevos, pero no hablar con ellos porque esa  lista no tiene los sockets de datos.

  Cuando aceptas un nuevo cliente debes añadirlo a esa lista, y cuando el cliente se va debes eliminarlo de esa lista. Aparentemente es lo que intentas hacer con `[mi_Socket].append()` y `[mi_Socket].remove()`. Por desgracia eso no funciona, ya que la lista sobre la que operas es una que se crea en ese momento como parte de esa expresión, y que desaparece otra vez al no estar asignada a ninguna variable.

  En definitiva, necesitas una variable `lista_sockets` que comenzará conteniendo tan solo a `mi_Socket`, y a la que añadirás y quitarás los sockets cuando se conecten.

  En el lado cliente esa variable no es necesaria, pues sólo tienes un socket, siempre el mismo, y la lista no crece ni mengua. Podemos dejar esa parte del cliente como estaba.

Aparte de ese error de concepto, había otros cuantos errores de sintaxis o de estilo. Por ejemplo:

- `while [mi_Socket]` En realidad el bucle del servidor ha de ser un bucle infinito, como el del cliente: `while True`.
- A `select()` le pasas una lista vacía en segunda posición, cuando deberías pasarle ahi la lista de sockets de datos esperando para escribir (y la lista vacía sería el tercer parámetro).
- Cuando recibes datos por un socket de datos, debes leer de ese socket de datos, pero en cambio tienes `datos = mi_Socket.recv(1024)`. Es decir, intentas recibir por un socket de escucha, lo que dará un error.
- En los `print()` has usado `&` donde querías poner `%`. En todo caso lo que se recomienda hoy día es usar `.format()` para formatear cadenas.
- Los datos que envíes por un socket han de codificarse como bytes. El intento de enviar una cadena como `"Python select server"` dará un error. Hay que usar `.encode()` sobre esa cadena para enviarla (y especificar un *encoding*, como "utf-8")
- Los datos que recibes de un socket llegan como bytes. Si quieres imprimirlos por pantalla será mejor convertirlos a cadena con el método `.decode()`, especificando de nuevo un *encoding* como "utf-8".
- Para mejorar la legibilidad, a la variable `i` se la podría llamar `sock`, para dejar más claro que es un socket.
- En el servidor, no necesitas usar `gethostname()` o `gethostbyname()` para obtener la IP del propio servidor. Puedes usar la IP especial `"0.0.0.0"` que representa a cualquier IP que el servidor tenga. Esto hace el código más breve.
- El cliente no debería obtener la IP a la que conectarse mediante `gethostname()`, sino de la línea de comandos (y no necesita convertirlo en IP usando `gethostbyname()` ya que el `socket.connect()` de python funciona también si le pasas un nombre de máquina en vez de una IP).

Con los cambios mencionados quedaría así:

### Servidor

```
import socket
import sys
import select

#Creando el socket TCP/IP
mi_Socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
mi_Socket.setblocking(0)

puerto = sys.argv[1]
dir_Servidor = ("0.0.0.0", (int(puerto)))

print("\nLevantamos %s puerto %s" %dir_Servidor)
mi_Socket.bind( dir_Servidor )

#Escuchando conexiones entrantes
mi_Socket.listen(5)

lista_sockets = [mi_Socket]
while True:
    ready_to_read, ready_to_write, in_error = select.select(lista_sockets, lista_sockets, [], 5)
    if len(ready_to_read) != 0:
        for sock in ready_to_read:
            if sock is mi_Socket:
                conexion_Cliente, dir_Cliente = sock.accept()
                conexion_Cliente.setblocking(0)
                lista_sockets.append(conexion_Cliente)
                print ("Conectado cliente: {}".format(dir_Cliente))
            else:
                print("Datos recibidos\n")
                datos = sock.recv(1024)
                if not datos:
                    print("Cliente desconectado")
                    lista_sockets.remove(sock)
                else:
                    print("\nLos datos son: {}".format(datos.decode("utf-8")))

    if len(ready_to_write) != 0:
        for sock in ready_to_write:
            sock.send("Python select server from Ubuntu.\n".encode("utf-8"))
```

### Cliente

```
import socket
import select
import sys

#Creando un socket TCP/IP

mi_Socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

#Conecta el socket en el puerto cuando el servidor esté escuchando
hostname = sys.argv[1]    
puerto = int(sys.argv[2])
dir_Servidor = (hostname, puerto)

print ("\nconectando a %s puerto %s" % dir_Servidor)
mi_Socket.connect(dir_Servidor)

while 1:
    ready_to_read, ready_to_write, in_error = select.select([mi_Socket], [mi_Socket], [], 5)
    if len(ready_to_read) != 0:
        buf = mi_Socket.recv(1024)
        if len(buf) != 0:
            print ("Datos recibidos: {}".format(buf.decode("utf-8")))
    if len(ready_to_write) != 0:
        mensaje = "Python select client from Ubuntu.\n"
        mi_Socket.send(mensaje.encode("utf-8"))
```

Eso sí, tal como están este par de clientes y servidor, en cuanto conectan uno con otro se meten en un bucle infinito de envíos y respuestas a toda velocidad, que hay que acabar abortando con Ctrl-C. Supongo que podrías cambiar el cliente para que repita su bucle sólo unas cuantas veces y luego desconecte.

Comment: Muchas gracias @abulafia! La verdad que vengo de C# de ahi que haga algunas cosas como & en los print para mostrar los datos. Mi idea es hacer un chat multiusuario. Primero quería poder mandar un mensaje en texto fijo y tras comprobar que lo recibo, poder enviar texto escrito por teclado y recibirlo en el otro lado (tipo un echo). La modificación, ¿la tendría que hacer en el send del cliente?

Comment: ¿A qué modificación te refieres? ¿Para pedir datos al usuario? Eso obviamente deberá ir en el cliente, sí. Ya que estás usando select, deberías añadir a la lista de descriptores a observar el de la entrada estándar. Cuando el usuario teclee algo y pulse intro, select() se desbloqueará y en `ready_to_read` tendrás el descriptor de teclado del que podrás leer con `input()` sin bloquearte. Los datos leidos los guardas para enviarlos por el socket cuando `ready_to_write` te lo indique.

Comment: Listo, al final con tu ayuda he conseguido hacer un "chat" entre los clientes. He tenido que usar netcat para ver qué me estaba haciendo. Dejo en el primer post el código ya solucionado para quien le ayude. Por cierto, @abulafia, ¿sabes si se puede enviar archivos entre clientes? Quiero decir, ahora escribo en un cliente un texto plano como tal y en el otro cliente lo recibo y viceversa, ¿cómo podría mandar un archivo tipo .txt y que se reciba en el otro cliente?

Comment: Está bien que hayas conseguido resolver tu problema, pero no deberías editar la pregunta para poner la solución, pues en ese caso la pregunta (y mi respuesta) ya carecerían de sentido si en la pregunta pones el código correcto y preguntas por qué te da errores. Lo que deberías hacer es dejar la preguna como estaba originalmente y **publicar una respuesta** con el código final que hace lo que querías. Es perfectamente válido responderse a sí mismo

Comment: Para enviar un archivo basta que el cliente abra el archivo y lo vaya leyendo (por ejemplo por líneas) enviando al otro extremo por el socket cada trozo que lea. Si quieres mezclar la posibilidad de enviar texto "normal" con envío de archivos, deberás inventar algún "lenguaje de comandos" para el cliente. Por ejemplo, si lo que teclea el usuario comienza por "FILE" sería un envío de fichero (y el resto de lo tecleado sería el nombre del fichero), mientras que si teclea otra cosa, sería para enviarlo "normalmente" como en el chat.